# How to swagger-document an ASP.NET Core action which reads Request.Body directly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui

I have a Controller action method which reads the `Request.Body` directly (instead of using File) for streaming and other purposes. The problem is there is no model binding and therefore Swagger doesn't document the contract. For example:

```
[HttpPost("upload")]
[DisableFormValueModelBinding]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadAsync()
{
  // Read from Request.Body manually, expecting content type to be multipart/*
  return Ok();
}
```

When loading Swagger UI, there is no way to upload a file, etc.

Is there any way to support this with attributes in ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The API:**

```
 [HttpPost]  
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(  
        [FromForm(Name = "myFile")]IFormFile myFile)  
    {  
            using (var fileContentStream = new MemoryStream())  
            {  
                await myFile.CopyToAsync(fileContentStream);  
                await System.IO.File.WriteAllBytesAsync(Path.Combine(folderPath, myFile.FileName), fileContentStream.ToArray());  
            }  
            return CreatedAtRoute(routeName: "myFile", routeValues: new { filename = myFile.FileName }, value: null); ;  
    }
```

**Operation filter**

```
public class SwaggerFileOperationFilter : IOperationFilter  
{  
    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)  
    {  
        if (operation.OperationId == "Post")  
        {  
            operation.Parameters = new List<IParameter>  
            {  
                new NonBodyParameter  
                {  
                    Name = "myFile",  
                    Required = true,  
                    Type = "file",  
                    In = "formData"  
                }  
            };  
        }  
    }  
}
```

**Startup- ConfigureServices**

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(  
    options =>  
    {  
        options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });  

        options.OperationFilter<SwaggerFileOperationFilter>();  
    });
```

**The result in swagger UI:**
[image]

The source is:[enter link description here](https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2019/august/handling-file-uploads-in-swagger-ui-with-aspnet-core/)

Comment: I cannot use IFormFile because I need to support streaming the file as the file may be very large. Though IFormFile allows Swagger to behave as I want, it also buffers the file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads

Comment: have you tried:
  var boundary = MultipartRequestHelper.GetBoundary(
        MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(Request.ContentType),
        _defaultFormOptions.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit);
    var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, HttpContext.Request.Body); 
as written this section:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0#upload-large-files-with-streaming?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am doing, but even Microsoft's sample doesn't work with Swagger. There is no way to upload a document in Swagger. So the question is, how do I decorate the method such that Swagger will provide the ability to upload a document?

Comment: I edited my answer, please share if you succeed with this...

Comment: Your answer uses IFormFile which I cannot do in my case. Also I am using the newer OpenApi stuff which doesn't have things like NonBodyParameter. However your answer got me 90% of the way there. I was able to create my own market attribute and use my own OpenApi code to do the same thing. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58516446) here does it... thanks for the pointer!